# Is Mitsuki an enemy of Boruto?

Tags: boruto

From a preview of episode 11 of Boruto: Naruto Next Generation, I think something about Mitsuki is going to be revealed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as it has been revealed, there is no conclusive proof. In the latest episode (Wednesday June 21st), Mitsuki told Boruto that he knows who is behind the "Ghost Incident", but that is where the episode finished.

He seems to be some sort of "a child" of Orochimaru.

Next episode, it will probably be revealed.

UPDATE:

I just read some Boruto manga, and since the manga refers to the future (Chuunin Exams), and Mitsuki is still there, then we can deduce that Mitsuki is **not** an enemy of Boruto.

Comment: Mitsuki is already confirmed to be the son (a home grown almost clone) of Orochimaru. Naruto_Gaiden: The Road Illuminated by the Full Moon tells that story. Orochimaru set up a complicated plot to get Mitsuki to discover his independence, and then let him go to Konoha.

Comment: Oh thank goodness! Thank you for answering mina!